# On disposition of an entire interest from Schedule K-1, are we required to report on only one of Schedule D or E?

Tags: united-states, taxes, passive-income

The IRS [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8582#en_US_2022_publink1000278179) for Form 8582 states the following for "Disposition of an Entire Interest":

> If you have an overall gain, report the income, losses, and prior year
> unallowed losses on Part IV or V.

If I report the capital gain on Form 8582, the examples suggest that it should also be on Schedule E. If I also report the capital gain on Schedule D as suggested by the form 4797 instructions, then the same capital gain would be double counted in my income.

**Is the implication that a disposition of a property that previously had suspended passive losses should ONLY be reported on (Form 8582, Form 4797, Schedule E) and NOT on Schedule D?**

Or should it be reported instead on (Form 8582, Form 4797, Schedule D) and NOT schedule E?